# Story collection with new house turning into hypercube

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short-story collection that could be about twenty years old, but the book was older, maybe 70s or 80s. After each story there was a sort of scientific explanation. The book was in Czech, but almost certainly translated from English.

One story was about a house designed as the 3D unfolding of a hypercube that collapses during an earthquake into an actual hypercube with people trapped inside. Another story that may have been in the same book was about a goose that lays actual golden eggs utilizing cold fusion.

UPDATE: Cleaning up I have found the book in a cupboard[image: the book]

Comment: http://www.e-shop.sidap.cz/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=4784

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The hypercube story is probably ["—And He Built a Crooked House—"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22%E2%80%94And_He_Built_a_Crooked_House%E2%80%94%22) by Robert Heinlein.

The story with the golden goose is almost certainly [Pâté de Foie Gras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A2t%C3%A9_de_Foie_Gras_(short_story)) by Isaac Asimov..

---

The only book listed on ISFDB in which they were *both* collected is the anthology [Where Do We Go from Here?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?54414)

And the format of the book is that Asimov follows each story with a short essay discussing the scientific points raised.

[image]

Comment: @Pete - Cheers for the edit. That seems like a clincher, especially since it's been translated into a pile of different languages.

Comment: Czech translation is called Těžká planeta, it is from 1979, https://www.databazeknih.cz/knihy/tezka-planeta-20289

Comment: And the hypercube story is called "Domeček jako klícka", I think.

Comment: @Krepi , Valorum Thanks, this is it. I remember now what the book looked like.